# How to convert List<string> to List<int>?

Tags: c#

My question is part of this problem:

I receive a collection of id's from a form. I need to get the keys, convert them to integers and select the matching records from the DB.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(FormCollection collection)
{
    var listofIDs = collection.AllKeys.ToList();  
    // List<string> to List<int>
    List<Dinner> dinners = new List<Dinner>();
    dinners= repository.GetDinners(listofIDs);
    return View(dinners);
}
```

Answer (score 496, accepted):

```
listofIDs.Select(int.Parse).ToList()
```

Comment: Exception raised - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
.net 4.0

Comment: @markthewizard1234 That will happen if your `listofIDs` is an `IQueryable<string>` that has not been executed. Execute it first with `ToList()` before you do the conversion: `listofIDs.ToList().Select(int.Parse).ToList()`

Comment: Im sure in 2013 this worked, but this no longer worked for me. Added a newer option below using linq statement.

Comment: This will throw an exception if any of the strings are not actually ints.  See the safe versions down below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712010/2340825

Comment: @MichaelHornfeck The first ToList should be AsEnumerable, no need to allocate a second List

Answer (score 48):

Here is a **safe** variant that filters out invalid ints:

```
List<int> ints = strings
    .Select(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : (int?)null)
    .Where(n => n.HasValue)
    .Select(n => n.Value)
    .ToList();
```

It uses an `out` variable introduced with C#7.0.

This other variant returns a list of nullable ints where `null` entries are inserted for invalid ints (i.e. it preserves the original list count):

```
List<int?> nullableInts = strings
    .Select(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : (int?)null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Great thanks!  Version for C# 6.0 below https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712010/2340825

Answer (score 46):

Using Linq ...

```
List<string> listofIDs = collection.AllKeys.ToList();  
List<int> myStringList = listofIDs.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 22):

What no TryParse?
**Safe LINQ version** that filters out invalid ints (for C# 6.0 and below):

```
List<int>  ints = strings
    .Select(s => { int i; return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : (int?)null; })
    .Where(i => i.HasValue)
    .Select(i => i.Value)
    .ToList();
```

credit to Olivier Jacot-Descombes for the idea and the C# 7.0 version.

Answer (score 15):

Using Linq:

```
var intList = stringList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList()
```

Comment: var intList = stringList.Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToList()

Answer (score 9):

I know it's old post, but I thought this is a good addition:
You can use [`List<T>.ConvertAll<TOutput>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx)

```
List<int> integers = strings.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s));
```

Comment: This can be simplified to
`List<int> integers = strings.ConvertAll(int.Parse);`

Answer (score 2):

Convert string value into integer list

```
var myString = "010"; 
int myInt;
List<int> B = myString.ToCharArray().Where(x => int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out myInt)).Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way, I think:

```
var listOfStrings = (new [] { "4", "5", "6" }).ToList();
var listOfInts = listOfStrings.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
```

Comment: I see this kind of pattern in lambda expressions often: _x => someMethod(x)_. You do know you should probably replace that with _someMethod_. With that your example becomes _listOfStrings.Select<string, int>(Convert.ToInt32);_. That's probably more readable, faster, shorter and did I already mention more elegant? The same goes for all others answering this question.

Comment: I'm getting an error when omitting the arrow syntax. This works: `List<string> sss = new List<string>();`  `IEnumerable<int> test1 = sss.Select<string, int>(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));` but this does not: `IEnumerable<int> test2 = sss.Select<string, int>(Convert.ToInt32);` The error is ambiguous call between the `string,int,int` and `string,int` versions of Select.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill for this simple problem. But for Try-Do methods in connection with Linq, I tend to use anonymous classes for more expressive code. It is similar to the answers from [Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46527059/4226080) and [BA TabNabber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48712010/4226080):

```
List<int> ints = strings
    .Select(idString => new { ParseSuccessful = Int32.TryParse(idString, out var id), Value = id })
    .Where(id => id.ParseSuccessful)
    .Select(id => id.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be using a linq statement. The recomended answer did not work for me in .NetCore2.0. I was able to figure it out however and below would also work if you are using newer technology.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(FormCollection collection)
{
    var listofIDs = collection.ToList().Select(x => x.ToString());
    List<Dinner> dinners = new List<Dinner>();
    dinners = repository.GetDinners(listofIDs);
    return View(dinners);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourEnumList.Select(s => (int)s).ToList()
```

Comment: Hi Patryk. Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better if you could write a little more description about the pretty concise solution you have posted. This is answer to a very old question on this website and would be reviewed by several users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it via LINQ

```
     var selectedEditionIds = input.SelectedEditionIds.Split(",").ToArray()
                            .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i) 
                             && int.TryParse(i,out int validNumber))
                            .Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Seems pretty wasteful to TryParse, which gives you the value, then simply throw that value out the window to then do a Parse. You're essentially double parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
intList = Array.ConvertAll(stringList, int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts array of string to array of long. It returns number of successfully converted values.

```
public static int strv_to_longv(string[] src, int src_offset, long[] dst, int dst_offset)
{
    int i = src_offset;
    int j = dst_offset;
    int ni = src.Length;
    int nj = dst.Length;
    while ((i < ni) && (j < nj))
    {
        j += long.TryParse(src[i], out dst[j]) ? 1 : 0;
        i++;
    }
    return j;
}
```

```
var line = "lemon 4 grape 1 garlic 77";
string[] words = line.Split(' ');
long[] longs = new long[10];
int l = strv_to_longv(words, 1, longs, 0);
//longs will be equal {4, 1, 77}
//l will be equal 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public List<int> ConvertStringListToIntList(List<string> list) 
  {
     List<int> resultList = new List<int>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        resultList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(list[i]));

     return resultList;
  }
```

Comment: Consider adding some textual explanation about your answer, instead of providing code only.