# Converting a List<String> to List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I read a list of numbers from a text document and saved them in a `List<String>` and I am trying to convert those numbers into a `List<int>`. The numbers are separated by spaces. Here is what I tried, assuming Numbers is the String list:

```
List<int> AllNumbers = Numbers.ConvertAll<int>(Convert.ToInt32);
```

When I try to use this is says "Input string was not in a correct format."

What is the correct way to convert a `List<String>` into a `List<int>`?

SAMPLE:

```
            string numbers = File.ReadAllText("numbers.txt");
            string[] allNumbers = numbers.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' },    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<string> List = new List<string>();
            List.AddRange(allNumbers);
```

I then want to take the List allNumbers and convert it to a List of integers.

The text file looks like this:

10 12 01 03 22....ect

Comment: So you have lists of strings, where each string consists of space-separated numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List<string> to List<int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201306/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your numbers are in a *single* string separated by spaces if so you can use Linq:

```
List<int> allNumbers = numbers.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

If you really have a `List<string>` numbers already simply:

```
List<int> allNumbers = numbers.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Or finally, if each string may contain multiple numbers separated by spaces:

```
List<int> allNumbers  = numbers.SelectMany(x=> x.Split(' ')).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: They are all in a single long string separated by spaces. Thank you, I will try these methods tonight.

Comment: No matter which method of these I use I am still getting string not in correct format. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Post a sample input and expected output, hard to say otherwise

Comment: Your sample input worked just fine for me - are you sure there are no non-numeric characters in your input file?

Comment: Somehow a random Z got in there...I am sad. My original code works fine hahaha. But I did learn some new ways to do the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each string in the list contains one or more integer numbers separated by spaces, you can try this approach:

```
var res = listOfNumbers
    .SelectMany(numStr => numStr.Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)))
    .ToList();
```

You can use method group instead of lambda in the last select: `Select(int.Parse)`