# Specified cast is not valid when trying to iterate through an IEnumerable<int> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, casting, iteration, ienumerable

so I am currently learning LINQ in C# and I was trying this `Cast<>` extension method which doesn't really seem to work out. When I try to iterate through the `IEnumerable<int>` values, it doesn't work it gives me the error :

> System.InvalidCastException("Specified cast is not valid").

This is the code:
(I've also tried to cast the 'result' variable into an array with `ToArray()` but it still didn't work, regardless of what I tried)

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(){ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10 };
IEnumerable<int> result = strings.Cast<int>();

foreach(int number in result){
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I've also tried to use 'var' instead of 'int' when trying to iterate through the IEnumerable result variable but it still doesn't work out, Here is an image of what it shows me:

[image]

Comment: You can't cast strings into ints, you need to convert the values, use Select instead.

Comment: Casting is not the same as converting (though there are cases where a cast can result in conversion). I would advise you to search for how to convert a string to an int.

Comment: Then why does Cast exist ? Isn't is supposed to transform every values from the IEnumerable into the given <TResult> value ?

Comment: @DavidGugea Please, check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201306/how-to-convert-liststring-to-listint. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cast is not for the value type casting, you cannot convert string to int by using Cast, this method is used to convert some array types that don't implement IEnumerable, e.g. ArrayList. So that you cannot use LINQ with ArrayList. If you want to query the ArrayList with LINQ syntax, you can use Cast to transform ArrayList into Enumerable, then the LINQ query is available.
Please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `int.TryParse` instead. So you can implement cast this way:

```
strings
    .Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out var result) ? result : 0)
    .ToArray()
```

or

```
strings
    .Select(x => int.TryParse(x, out var result) ? result : throw new InvalidCastException(message: ""))
    .ToArray()
```